# trouble creating form macros in laravel

Tags: laravel, macros

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create a form macros but it is telling me

> Error
>
> Class 'App\Services\Macros' not found (View:
> C:\Apache24\htdocs\webflow\resources\views\home.blade.php)

**Macros.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Collective\Html\FormBuilder;

class Macros extends FormBuilder 
{

    public function selectYearList($name, $selected = null, $option = array())
    {
        $list =
        [
            'Select',
            '2020',
            '2021',
        ];
    }
}
```

*the $list above is for testing purpose.

**MacroServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use App\Services\Macros;
use Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider;

    class MacroServiceProvider extends HtmlServiceProvider
    {
        public function register()
        {
            parent::register();
    
            $this->app->singleton('form', function ($app) {
                $form = new Macros($app['html'], $app['url'], $app['view'], $app['session.store']->token());
                return $form->setSessionStore($app['session.store']);
            });
        }
    
    }
```

and also is it possible to get data from a controller to use in a macro? I want to create a dropdown using data from the controller.

Comment: Try `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` or using `artisan clear-compiled` on server side

Comment: Also, are you 100% sure there is no mistake about the path of the file ? Is it really inside `app\services\macros.php` ? No typo or anything ?

Comment: it is telling me 

Class App\Services\Macros located in C:/Apache24/htdocs/webflow/app\Macros.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

the Macros.php file is directly  in App folder but I also tried App\Macro and its still doesnt work.

Comment: I think I got it. I had to change the namespace in marcros.php to App only and its not giving me any errors any more but my second question still remains. is it possible to get data from a controller to use in a macro? I want to create a dropdown using data from the controller.

Comment: add `namespace App;` to your Macro.php and add  `use App\Macro` in Controller